# Generating .dbml file from SQL Server 2008 ONLY IF NOT Sql Server 2000

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, dbml

Is it possible Generating .dbml file from SQL Server 2008 ONLY IF NOT Sql Server 2000 using sql management tools,

There is no visual studio installed so that I could use SQLMetal but even with that can I generate .dbml for couple of tables ?

Comment: I think the answers to your questions are no and no. However if you don't have visual studio then what are you going to do with the DBML file? If you want to use it elsewhere then why not just script out the DB schema into a SQL file instead.

Comment: @BenRobinson I don't have it on the server installed, but if there is no other option, then I must need to ask admin to install it